# How to import the MS Word document content and typesetting?

Tags: import, office

I have a vocabulary with phonetics [here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1sTBwffv9W2m5BzMUy6ddEA)(the extracted password is: `1234`). I import these contents by saving the `docx` file as an `XML` file.

```
Import["D:\\360Downloads\\考博英语10000词汇表.docx", "Text", 
 CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
Import["C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\考博英语10000词汇表\\考博英语10000词汇表.xml", "CDATA", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
```

However, after importing this `XML` file with the above method, there are a lot of errors in phonetic information.

```
Import["C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\考博英语10000词汇表\\考博英语10000词汇表.xml", \
"Plaintext", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
```

When I use the above code to import the data of this file, many unnecessary line breaks appear.

[image]

I tried to typeset it by function `StringCases`, but failed:

```
s = StringReplace[
   Import["C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\考博英语10000词汇表\\考博英语10000词汇表.\
xml", "Plaintext", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], "\n" -> ""];
StringCases[s, (x : CharacterRange["a", "z"] ..) ~~ (y__ /; 
     StringFreeQ[y, "["]) ~~ CharacterRange["a", "z"] .. ~~ 
   "[" ~~ __ ~~ "]" :> {x, y}]
```

I want to know what I can do to import the contents of this file according to the following format:

```
{{abate,{ə'beit},{v．减轻，减退；废除}},{aberrant,{æ'berənt},{a.畸变的;异常的;脱离常轨的}},...{accent ,{'æksənt, æk'sent},{ n．腔调，口音；重音，重音符号,v．加重读}}...}
```

Comment: using python package `python-docx`. In mma, you can use `ExternalEvaluate` to communicate with python.

Comment: @partida Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way (remove the last set of words):

```
s = StringReplace[
   Import["C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\考博英语10000词汇表\\考博英语10000词汇表.\
xml", "Plaintext", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], "\n" -> ""];
sol = StringSplit[s, 
   x : ((CharacterRange["a", "z"] | Whitespace) .. ~~ "[" ~~ 
       Shortest[y__] ~~ "]") :> Style[x, FontColor -> Red]] ;
Partition[sol // Rest // Most, 2]
```

[image]